# Masonry: With a 2 column layout, how do I have 1 column wider than the other one?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

So I'm trying to create a 2 column masonry layout, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq6LJ.png

I'm not sure how to get this to work automatically, as in, not having to set a specific width on each grid item.

Since I'm just looping over articles, none of them have a specific width set. I just need the ones on the right side to be 60% wide, and the ones on the left side to be 30% wide.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <article class="grid-item">
      <!-- Content -->
  </article>
</div>
```

[Here is a codepen of my attempt at getting this to work.](http://codepen.io/tenold/pen/NAJLWm)

Is this even possible with Masonry?

Maybe with another grid library?

Answer (score 0):

No, from what I have read, Masonry is not intended to produce fixed size single columns of items like you are wanting so...

I would acquire the window width using jquery and assign a percentage of that width to your container element like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cWidth = $(window).width() * .7; // 70% or whatever you want
    cWidth.toFixed(0);
    $('#container').width(cWidth);

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        var crWidth = $(window).width() * .7; // 70% or whatever you want
        crWidth.toFixed(0);
        $('#container').width(crWidth);
    });
});
```

Then set your child elements' (column) widths in CSS like this...

```
.left-column {
    width: 35%;
}

.right-column {
    width: 65%
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't have a differentiating class like that on grid item elements. That's the main issue.

Comment: I don't think Masonry is going to work the way you want it to for your need.